# Can we add our own images in primeface's button

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

In p:button in need add my own image(any image which i want to include).

```
`<p:button  icon="ui-icon-star" title="Icon Only">

</p:button>
```

`Can i add like this

```
 <p:button  icon=""/images/someimage.png"" title="Icon Only">

    </p:button>`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The icon attribute of `<p:button>` needs a CSS class, you can not give it a image path. Example:

PrimeFaces button:

```
<p:button  icon="my-icon"  />
```

CSS:

```
.my-icon {
    background-image: url("images/myicon.png");
}
```

Comment: hi mark am not getting the image , i have included the css file in the header of my xhtml and include the .my-icon class in the css file but am not getting the image

Comment: I am using primeface 3.3.1 , is it possible in that version

Comment: Yes, this will work in PrimeFaces 3.3.1 as well. Make sure the path to your image in your CSS is correct.

Comment: thanks Mark , its worked but the image is coming along with button background i need only the image , is it possible ??

Comment: If you only want the image and not the button look at doing it this way .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9924603/how-to-make-pgraphicimage-clickable